# $x^2(\log_{10}(x))^5=100$ : solution of this equation

Tags: logarithms

I needed help with the equation in the title, the base of $\log$ is $10$

I have tried the substitution of $x^2$ as $100$ and gotten $x= 10$ but I do not know how to solve it algebraically.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This equation does not have an algebraic solution in the ordinary sense of the word. You made a lucky guess.

Comment: I got the lucky guess method , are you 100% sure about the no algebraic solution part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using logarithm properties you get
$$
x^2 \log_{10}^5(x) = 10^2 \color{darkblue}{\implies} x^\frac{2}{5} \log_{10}(x) = 10^\frac{2}{5}  \color{darkblue}{\implies}\log_{10}\left(x^{ x^\frac{2}{5} }\right) = 10^\frac{2}{5}  \color{darkblue}{\implies}  \color{green}{x}^{\color{green}{x}^{\frac{2}{5}}} = \color{green}{10}^{\color{green}{10}^{\frac{2}{5}} }
$$
where by inspection you get $\color{green}{x} = \color{green}{10}$ as a solution.

---

By repeating the previous procedure, the general problem would in turn become solving
$$
x^{x^{a}} = b
$$
for some $a,b$ and $b>0$. For this, we can employ the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Generalizations), which is defined to be such that if $xe^x =z$ then $x = W(z)$. We get
$$
x^{x^{a}} = b  \color{darkblue}{\implies} \color{purple}{a}\ln(x) e^{a\ln(x)} =  \color{purple}{a}\ln(b)\color{darkblue}{\implies}a\ln(x) = W\left(a\ln(b) \right) \color{darkblue}{\implies} x= e^{\frac{W\left(a\ln(b) \right)}{a}}
$$
In your case we would have $a= \frac{2}{5}$ and $b = 10^{{10}^{\frac{2}{5}}}$, thus
\begin{align*}
x =  \exp\left[{\frac{W\left(\frac{2}{5}\ln\left(10^{{10}^{\frac{2}{5}}}\right) \right)}{\frac{2}{5}}} \right]=  \exp\left[\frac{5}{2}W\left({10}^{\frac{2}{5}}\ln\left(10^{\frac25}\right) \right) \right]
\end{align*}
but since $W(xe^{x}) = x$ by definition of the Lambert-W, substituting $x=\ln(y)$ gives $W(y \ln(y)) = \ln(y)$, which allows us to simplify
$$
x = \exp\left[\frac{5}{2}\ln\left(10^{\frac{2}{5}}\right) \right] = \exp[\ln(10)] = 10
$$
as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that helped